# php artisan optimize error while compiling views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

versions:
Laravel: 4.3-dev.
After running this command: `php artisan optimize -vvv` the following error accured:

```
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
Compiling views



  [ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                   
  file_put_contents(/path/to/laravel/project/app/storage/views/acdf854d7379225870611046cb29be6f): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  



Exception trace:
 () at /path/to/laravel/project/storage/meta/compiled.php:4529
 Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError() at n/a:n/a
 file_put_contents() at /path/to/laravel/project/storage/meta/compiled.php:4529
 Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php:80
 Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler->compile() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php:150
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->compileViews() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php:71
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->fire() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:112
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:252
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:100
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:891
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /path/to/laravel/project/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /path/to/laravel/project/artisan:59


optimize [--force] [--psr]
```

The error shows that the view compiler try to save a file in the storage `file_put_contents(/path/to/laravel/project/app/storage/views/acdf854d7379225870611046cb29be6f)` folder but with the new Laravel folder structure the storage folder is not under the app folder any more but the optimizer still refer to the old path from Laravel 4.2 when the line should be `file_put_contents(/path/to/laravel/project/storage/views/acdf854d7379225870611046cb29be6f)`, how could I fix that?

## Update:

By the way, I have mcrypt extension installed.
Deleting the compiled.php file didn't fix the error.
And deleting the vendor directory and running `composer install` didn't help.

## update 2:

The new folder structure of laravel 4.3 have the storage directory at the same level as the app directory, the optimizer when reaching the `compiling view` step it fails with `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error since artizan optimizer try to save the view to a view file under the storage under the app directory not at the same level at it.
This happened in a new laravel installation, I didn't start coding yet.

Comment: maybe try `sudo php artisan optimize`

Comment: I tried that, didn't help, check update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not suggest upgrading from 4.2 to 4.3 it is still in very early beta and there have been rumours that Taylor is going to release it as 5.0 instead due to all of the re-structuring and breaking changes when upgrading.

Try creating a new laravel 4.3 project and from there copy your code into  the new install.  Remember the entire app is now namespaced including controllers, so this will require to to add namepaces to all your existing code and classes as well.

Comment: I don't know what happened but I reinstall Laravel and it worked, still don't know what was wrong though, thanks anyway.